# appending input to the end of api call in python

Tags: python, json, bots, telegram

```
def i(bot,update,args):
    coin=args
    infoCall =requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/").json()
    coinId = infoCall ['categories']
    update.message.reply_text(coinId)
```

I would like to add to the end of the api request the args declared in coins=args so that it retrieves the info my user requests but this is the error i get

```
coinId = infoCall ['categories']
KeyError: 'categories'
```

which my guess is because its not formating the request correctly so the api is giving a 404 and not the info being requested

```
def i(bot,update,args):
    coin=args
    infoCall =requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/").json()
    infoCall = json.loads(infoCall)+str(coins) 
    coinId = infoCall['categories']
    update.message.reply_text(str (coinId))
```

after adding this, this is the new error i get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 279, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self)
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\commandhandler.py", line 173, in handle_update
    return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
  File "C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/coding_crap/CryptoBotBetav2.py", line 78, in i
    infoCall = json.loads(infoCall)+str(coins)
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
```

Comment: Ok, I'm wrong here, you `infoCall` is retrieving the information in a list, inside the list there are dict, what you want to append to them now? do you want to append a coinIds to each of the `dict`?

Comment: if i can just add my users input to the end of that api request it would pull back the call i want to make to the api, thus opening the json info i need to send to them. *sorry, im really new to programming and figured the best way to learn would to be just jump in head first and learn hands on since all the videos did do a whole lot for me*

Comment: Please Show me your expected output.

Comment: but yes, my idea is to allow my telegram bot to accept /info *user input* then fetch the api call that finds that info.

Comment: user types this in telegram chat: /bitcoin     -this then take /*bitcoin* and adds it to the end of the api call to call https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin       - that searches the json for ['categories'] and sends that info back to the user

Comment: Your response is not having _categories_. can you post what exact output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin       - is the exact output im trying to call. it has a section called "categories" in which it tells what its type of crypto is. I would love to allow my user to call the description info but i get a "message to long" error, so if someone could tell me how to shorten that you would be amazing!

Comment: I have posted the answer. You can have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are not appending the *args* param to the api point that's why you were getting the error. You need to append the `'bitcoin'` to the api point before you make the request rather than on the output. 
A typical example would be as follow. I have removed the *update* and other unused variables. You can put them as you need.

```
import requests
def i(args):
    coin=args
    infoCall =requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+ args).json()
    coinId = infoCall ['categories']
    print(coinId)
    # update.message.reply_text(coinId)
i('bitcoin')
```

**Output:**

> ['Cryptocurrency']

Comment: TypeError: i() got multiple values for argument 'args' is the error i get with your solution

Comment: kindly copy paste my snippet and execute in a standalone file

Comment: You need to modify my solution into something which you need. I have solved your `KeyError` issue

Comment: thank you! issue solved, kinda.... now the messsage is to long and i would like to only select a certain amount

Comment: Glad I could help. kindly click on the tick symbol to accept my answer if my answer helped you to solve.

Comment: i have, it says recorded but wont let me up it due to rep